# Display error message from Admin_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, extends

I had create core/Admin_Controller.php and I created page controller but when I run page controller there is error displaying
"Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\application\controllers\admin\Page.php on line 4"

```html
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    { 
        
        parent::__construct();

      
    }

}
```

page controller

```html
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends Admin_Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('admin_m');
  $this->load->model('page_m');
 }

 public function index(){
  $data['title'] = 'Press Release';
        $data['page'] = $this->page_m->show_list();
        $this->load->view(THEME_DIR_ADMIN.'common/admin_header');
        $this->load->view(THEME_DIR_ADMIN.'page/list', $data);
        $this->load->view(THEME_DIR_ADMIN.'common/admin_footer');
 }
}
```

Do I need to update any file?

Answer (score 0):

core/Admin_Controller.php

```
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    { 
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and

config/config.php

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Admin_';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you don't want all your Prefixes to be `Admin_`, however if you do, @Lifu Lin's answer will work.

I would create MY_Controller.php in the core directory as you have, but I would add the Admin_Controller code in this file, like this;

**MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    ...
}

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {

}
```

Both classes in the same file, will work fine (this is how I do it on my projects)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` file put next code:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (substr($class,0,3) !== 'CI_') {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
});
```